# rails undefined method `relation_delegate_class' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i'm trying to set up a has many and belong to function between a few events i have on my database

The issue i have is below:

```
2.3.3 :003 > event.ticketmasters
NoMethodError: undefined method `relation_delegate_class' for Ticketmaster:Module
```

Here are my two models

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ticketmasters

class Ticketmasters < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
```

What am I doing wrong? (can provide more code if needed), In the database i have two rows in the ticketmasters table with `event_id` column inside it and they have the same `event_id` inside it.

Thank you

Comment: What's `has_permalink`, where does it come from?

Comment: has_permalink is a third party gem, Its not relevant to the question and should be removed, Its just sat in my models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class should not be "Ticketmasters" it should be "Ticketmaster"

That's the class the relation is looking for.

If for some reason you must use "Tickemaasters" (and I hope you don't) then you should do

```
  has_many :ticketmasters, class_name: 'Ticketmasters'
```

To override rails default behavour.